# Strange compilation error with TypeScript and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular application, I have a service with a method to get a simple string from a rest server. This code does not compile :

```
getText(): Promise<String> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',  accept: 'text/plain'}),
      responseType: 'text'
    }    
    return firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get(this.endPoint + this.publicUrl, httpOptions))
  }
```

This neither :

```
  getText(): Promise<String> {
    const httpOptions: Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',  accept: 'text/plain'}),
      responseType: 'text'
    }    
    return firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get(this.endPoint + this.publicUrl, httpOptions))
  }
```

But this compiles and works :

```
  getText(): Promise<String> {
    return firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get(this.endPoint + this.publicUrl, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',  accept: 'text/plain'}),
      responseType: 'text'
    }))
  }
```

Why cannot I use variable as second parameter in `HttpClient.get()` ?

Comment: tips: do not use `String` as a type, `string` is a better choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`httpClient.get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) has a complexe signature with 15 overloads.

A bunch of them depens on the type of `responseType`.

When you write

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',  accept: 'text/plain'}),
  responseType: 'text'
}
```

`httpOptions` is inferred as `{headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string;}`.

As you can see `responseType` is widen to `string`, this is why TS isn't able to find the right overload you're looking for.

Using `as const` can fix the issue here, `responseType` would not be widen anymore and defined as `responseType: 'test'`.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',  accept: 'text/plain'}),
  responseType: 'text'
} as const
```